# Is there any reason to use css box-shadow over drop-shadow?

Tags: filter, css, dropshadow

Assuming client compatibility, is there any situation where CSS `box-shadow` is preferable to `filter: drop-shadow`.

From [the article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/filters/understanding-css/) it seems like `drop-shadow` is a HW accelerated superset of `box-shadow`. This means that we should basically always use `drop-shadow` instead of `box-shadow`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is only one difference between `box-shadow` and `filter: drop-shadow`. With `box-shadow` you can use **inset shadows**, but you can't do it with `filter: drop-shadow`. **All depended on you.** [Check this example](http://jsfiddle.net/vule/MUYBZ/).

Why is better to use `box-shadow` insted of `filter: drop-shadow`?

- Better browser support
- Most of developers use it
- Less code, more options
- You can use inset shadows
- You can use more than one shadow

Also, there is one [example with image](http://jsfiddle.net/vule/SWuRf/) where is better to use `filter: drop-shadow`. The first one has rectangle shadow, but the other one has shadow which follow the edge of image.

Comment: Most of the bullet points are now invalid. The filter uses the shape of the element which is great for images with transparency. The downside is that the spread parameter is not supported and there's no inset option. The obvious comparison here is with text-shadow, and there's no difference between the 2 in options, although the end result is a bit different.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that there is limited browser support for `filter` at the moment with `box-shadow` being much more supported.

- [Browser support for filter](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters)
- [Browser support for box-shadow](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow)

Answer (score 0):

Another difference: CSS `filter` creates a new stacking context, whereas `box-shadow` doesn't, so if you don't want to deal with that, you might want to stick with `box-shadow`. A demo of absolutely positioned tooltips inside drop-shadow vs box-shadow cards: https://jsfiddle.net/lexw11/uro0hqbx/137/